# Why does this UPDATE statement fail in H2?

Tags: sql, h2

This UPDATE statement works when run against Postgres, but fails when run against H2. What's the equivalent H2 statement?

```
UPDATE award_details
SET award_id = a.id
FROM awards a
WHERE a.award_details_id = award_details.id;
```

The H2 error message is:

```
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 42000
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "​​[*]
UPDATE AWARD_DETAILS
SET AWARD_ID = A.ID
FROM AWARDS A
WHERE A.AWARD_DETAILS_ID = AWARD_DETAILS.ID"; SQL statement:
```

Comment: According to its documentation (http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#update), `UPDATE` in H2 does not support a `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current update syntax looks to be Postgres style.  Instead use correlated subquery update syntax:

```
UPDATE award_details aw
SET award_id = (SELECT a.id FROM awards a WHERE a.award_details_id = aw.id);
```